# Rails 5 - accepts_nested_attributes_for when building multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

**EDIT 2:**
More progress. I can now save the data properly. Now to see if I can update it.

**EDIT 1:** 
*I've made some progress and can render the fields in the view with the following code, though I am having trouble saving the data. It also doesn't feel like "the rails way" as they say. Is there a better approach to doing this?*

> **Original Question:**
>
> In my application, I have a `Daily` model which holds a store ID and
>   timestamps. Each day, for each `Store`, a form is to be created to
>   display a field for each service in the `Service` model. This data
>   will be saved to a `DailyDatum` model. One record for each service
>   which references the daily_id.
>
> So my question is, in the form for creating a new form for the daily
>   object, how do I render a field for each service in the `Service`
>   model?

**The Idea:**

- The user can create a `Service`.
- Each `Store` has one `Daily` record for any given date.
- Each `Daily` has many `DailyDatum`.
- Each `DailyDatum` holds a record of each `Service` in the services table for that day along with a value.

**Updated code:**

Daily Controller:

```
def new
  @daily = Daily.new
  @services = []
  Service.all.each do |s|
    service = @daily.daily_data.build
    service.service_id = s.id
    @services << service
  end
end

def create
  @daily = Daily.new(daily_params)
  if @daily.save
    params["services"].each do |service|
      data = DailyDatum.new(service_params(service))
      data.daily_id = @daily.id
      data.save
    end
    redirect_to dailies_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def service_params(my_params)
    my_params.permit(:daily_id, :service_id, :value)
  end
```

Model - DailyDatum.rb

```
class DailyDatum < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :daily
  belongs_to :service
end
```

Model - Daily.rb

```
class Daily < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :daily_data
  belongs_to :store
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :daily_data
end
```

Model - Service.rb

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service_group, optional: true
  has_many :daily_data
end
```

Model - Store.rb

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :store_users, inverse_of: :store
  has_many :users, through: :store_user
  has_many :dailies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :store_users, allow_destroy: true
end
```

View:

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <tr>
  <%= fields_for 'services[]', service do |s| %>
  <%= s.hidden_field :service_id, value: service.service_id %>
    <td><%= s.label :value, service_name(service.service_id) %></td>
    <td><%= s.text_field :value %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please update your questions with the model code daily and service.

Comment: Updated with models.